# Why does this code use an oversized array instead of a Map?

Tags: java

[Here's JBoss JSTL implementation for the EscapeXML tag](https://github.com/jboss/jboss-jstl-api_spec/blob/4ad412ae5be1ae606b8d33c188cb3d98bfcbe84c/src/main/java/org/apache/taglibs/standard/util/EscapeXML.java#L45)

```
public class EscapeXML {

    private static final String[] ESCAPES;

    static {
        int size = '>' + 1; // '>' is the largest escaped value
        ESCAPES = new String[size];
        ESCAPES['<'] = "&lt;";
        ESCAPES['>'] = "&gt;";
        ESCAPES['&'] = "&amp;";
        ESCAPES['\''] = "&#039;";
        ESCAPES['"'] = "&#034;";
    }
  //omitted
}
```

Why is `ESCAPES` a 61 elements array? What are the implication of using a `Map<Character,String>` instead?

Comment: The main implications are that it would probably take more memory ... and it would definitely be slower.

Comment: This is *essentially* a `Map<int, String>` (or `Map<char, String>` depending on how you look at it) with guaranteed `O(1)` access (done efficiently as an array lookup). A micro-optimization that I imagine has been tested to be worth it.

Comment: A `HashMap` typically consumes ~100 bytes per entry, not including the key and value themselves.  A `String[]` consumes ~ 4 or ~8 bytes per entry.  5 * 100 > 61 * 8

Comment: If you look at the source you linked to, `getEscape()` would probably have to call `Map.containsKey()` which is slower than `if (c < ESCAPES.length) {`

Comment: Can somebody explain how on earth is the code trying to use characters for array index in java and not getting a compile error?

Comment: @alirezafnatica a `char` in java is a numerical value. You can also compare them using e.g. `if('a'>'b')` or perform `'a'+'b'`. In this case it is automatically widened to an `int` to be used as an array index.

Comment: @alirezafnatica `char` to `int` is a widening conversion not requiring an explicit cast, so `int x = 'a';` works just like `arr['a'] = foo;`.

Comment: Wow thanks, that's weird though. I thought character is 2 bytes so it can't be Widened to `byte`. So it is converted to `int`. That's reaonable

Comment: Think on use-case perspective and take decision accordingly, You can chose `String[]` at first place, but if you are looking for efficient read use-case then `Map<Character, String>` would be a right choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main reason is performance. Each map query needs to get the hashcode, and then calculate the position of the array in the map, and the array can be obtained directly. The following is a simple test, querying 10,000 times separately, the array is about 10 times faster than the map.

```
array query result: cost time= 184041
map query result: cost time= 1677042
```

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * @author jahe
 * @date 2022/1/9
 * @note
 */
public class ArrayMapTest {
    private char[] chars = {'<', '>', '&', '\'', '"'};
    private char[] charsForQuery = new char[10000];
    @Before
    public void init(){
        Random random = new Random(5);
        random.nextInt(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < charsForQuery.length; i++) {
            charsForQuery[i] = chars[random.nextInt(5)];
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(charsForQuery));
    }
    @Test
    public void test() {
        int size = '>' + 1;
        String[] ESCAPES = new String[size];
        ESCAPES['<'] = "&lt;";
        ESCAPES['>'] = "&gt;";
        ESCAPES['&'] = "&amp;";
        ESCAPES['\''] = "&#039;";
        ESCAPES['"'] = "&#034;";
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        doTestForArray(ESCAPES);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("array query result: cost time= " + (end - start));

        Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put('<', "&lt;");
        map.put('>', "&gt;");
        map.put('&', "&amp;");
        map.put('\'', "&#039;");
        map.put('"', "&#034;");
        start = System.nanoTime();
        doTestForMap(map);
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("map query result: cost time= " + (end - start));

    }
    private void doTestForArray(String[] ESCAPES){
        for (char c : charsForQuery) {
            String str = ESCAPES[c];
        }
    }
    private void doTestForMap(Map<Character, String> map){
        for (char c : charsForQuery) {
            String s = map.get(c);
        }
    }
}
```